Using Moq how can I setup a method that has an out parameter with that out parameter returing a mock of another interface?
I have an interface that has a method which has an out parameter which is another interface. Something like this:
bool GetA(string name, out IA a);

I can find plenty of examples of doing this with simple out parameters like ints and strings but I want the out parameter to be assigned to a Mock object of that interface. I thought something like the following would work but it doesn't
Mock<IB> b = new Mock<IB>();
Mock<IA> a = new Mock<IA>();
b.Setup(m => m.GetA("test", out a.Object)).Returns(true);


Look at this answer in the specified duplicate. You need to define a delegate for the method with the out parameter, and then use b.Setup(...).Callback(new MyDelegate((string s, out IA i) => i = a.Object)).Returns(...)
